# Accessing ArcGIS Portal user account using ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

Using ArcGIS API for Python on Portal, I need to see

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS(url="https://xxx.xxx.com/portal", username="xxx", password="xxx")
print(gis.version)
user = gis.User('abc123@xxxx.com')
print(user.fullName)
```

But I am getting this error on `print(user.fullName)`

```
AttributeError: 'GIS' object has no attribute 'User'
```

while the `arcgis.gis` module has a class for `User` at [Here](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#user)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User` is a class in the `arcgis.gis` module, not a property of the `arcgis.gis.GIS` class.

The [examples](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#user) show a couple of ways of getting a `User` object:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS, User

url="https://xxx.xxx.com/portal"
username="xxx@xxx"
password="xxx"

gis = GIS(url=url, username=username, password=password)

# Ask the GIS object for a User
user = gis.users.get(username)
print(user.fullName)

# Get the User directly
user = User(gis, username)
print(user.fullName)
```